# Disable a button by clicking on another button Java/Xml/Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I wrote this code to disable using another button by clicking this button in Java/Android Studio but it is not working.

```
 public void btnPowerCheck_onClick(View v) {
        SendMessage("43");
        Button ButtonBtnPowerCheck =  findViewById(R.id.btnPowerCheck);
        ButtonBtnPowerCheck.setEnabled(false);

    }
```

Comment: since you didn't share much code, may I ask : have you tried to display something to the log when you click the first button, might be the case that this onClickListener is not configured correctly to work when you press the first button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for response, It was my problem, I entered tags and ids wrong